# SMS alert not getting On DND Numbers when Web site is Down

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to find out the Uptime and Downtime of a website using [article which monitors using Google Docs scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/website-monitoring-with-sms-alerts/25382/). The script also sends a text message using SMS when a site is down.

I used 5 Mobile numbers for testing, out of which only one phone was able to get the notification. The other 4 phones have  [DND(Do Not Disturb) activated](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/), which I presume is the reason why the SMS doesn't get delivered.

My Concern is that while associating with Google calender when I put that DND(Do Not Disturb) number they got verification code and after putting that Verification code they register. So for verification they are getting the SMS but they are not getting the alert when web site is down or up.

Comment: honestly you're better off using a service like [pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/). Also, this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

A service like [downnotifier.com](http://www.downnotifier.com) is also free (except the price for SMS messages) and made to do these kind of things.